# two figures next to one with caption at same level

Tags: floats, subfloats, sidewaysfigure

I want to place two figures next to one with the caption of the one on the left with the one on the bottom right at the exact same level

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox{\bigpicturebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\sbox{\bigpicturebox}{%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
  \scalebox{1}[1.2]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Big picture}
\end{subfigure}
}

\usebox{\bigpicturebox}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\bigpicturebox][s]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{.59\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.59\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}

\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A rude solution where small images heights are approximately  `\ht/2` to big image (measured in `\picbox`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newbox{\picbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\sbox{\picbox}{
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}%
}    
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\textwidth}%\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\usebox\picbox
\caption{Big picture}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.45\ht\picbox]{example-image-a}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.45\ht\picbox]{example-image-b}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: real height of big picture is equal to `\ht` + `\dp`, however `\dp` is ~0 and at small images you need to consider height of one subcaption (probably it is about `\baselineskip`). Therefore in proposed solution is considered only `0.45\ht\picbox`, rest of big image height is reserved for one small image subcaption.